# How do I begin programming an animation that I plan to integrate into a website?

Tags: animation

I want to create an animation/visualization for a website that I'm making, but I have no idea how to get started. I'm planning to use a map as a background, and to have animation on top of it to simulate changes over time once a start button is pressed.

The thing is, I want this animation to be dynamic (aka, it depends on the data from the website, so if users submit more entries, the animation updates to reflect those).

How on earth do I get started with something like that? What kind of language should I use to program it? I have only a little experience with web programming...googling the issue didn't help me much, although it seems that GWT and Actionscript are options...? Is javascript enough in itself, or are there pre-existing libraries that would make this easier?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: By GWL, do you mean WebGL? If so, it only works on just a few browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what kind of animation this should be, what level of interactivity it should provide both with the user and the page content. I imagine this goes beyond some shrinking, moving, hiding of the web page elements and similar RIA stuff.

I hope my answer will at leasy get you started on the subject.

Generally for a web site animation or advanced dynamic/interactive content I think you should compare the following possibilities:

#### JavaScript

I think JavaScript would be a very good, natural and self suffiecient choice for this task. It has all the power to make things move and interact with the user and it can also interact with anything on the page including data, events such as submitting of data, and can also update the data on the page in the background using Ajax, without interrupting the run of the animation for example.

If we talk about animation specifically there is huge amount of libraries, but I don't have experience with any of them. For example you could check out the **[gameQuery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/)** (a jQuery plugin), **[$fx](http://fx.inetcat.com/)**, **[jsAnim](http://jsanim.com/)** or many other game engines or 2D animation frameworks such as some of **[these at GitHub](https://gist.github.com/768272)**, though many of them already use HTML 5 features.

#### JavaScript with HTML 5

Other good choice would be to use JavaScript along with some nice features that HTML 5 brought to the table.

I suggest you take a look at **[Impact](http://impactjs.com/)** framework and some of the web browser games based on it, which is a good demonstration of what HTML 5 is capable of. Again there are many alternatives, such as the ones from the abovementioned GitHub list.

If HTML 5 is appealing to you I also suggest you to read an article or two on HTML 5 pros and cons such as backwards compatibility with older browsers. If none of those problems would matter to you, then HTML 5 could be a very viable choice.

#### Other "dynamic stuff" technologies for the web

These can be:

- **Flash** (ActionScript, which you mention, is a programming language of Flash)
- **Silverlight**, which is a .NET technology
- **Java applets**, which are programmed in Java, don't confuse this with JavaScript
- or maybe some others which I don't know about

Every one of these technologies has its own drawbacks, concepts, development tools ans so on. They all require specific extensions/plugins to be installed on the client's browser. I suggest you read some overview on each one of them or perhaps some comparison articles to see if they suit your needs.